# UI Button reference not visible in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I declared my Button[] public so i can reference it from my inspector

but it does not appear in my inspector. Please help!!!

I tried restarting the C# as well as re-importing everything in unity....

public rocket rocket;

```
 public Button[] levelButtons; 

void Start()
{
    for(int i=1 ; i<levelButtons.Length ; i++)
    {
      //  if(i + 1 > rocket.level)
        levelButtons[i].SetEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: where the size of Button[]? Did you create before using it?

Comment: Did you try the [SerializeField] attribute?

Comment: (Disclaimer: I have no knowledge about unity) - Is `levelButtons` declared in the same class as your `Start` method? Since I don't know what an "inspector" is, maybe this "inspector" wants a public property and not a public variable try this `public Button[] levelButtons { get; set; }`

Comment: Maybe you're using a different `'Button'` namespace? Check if you're using the right namespace on top of the script (Unity's own UI-Button is inside `UnityEngine.UI.Button`)

Comment: @Clovis Ignacio Ferreira Yes i tried it....still doesnot work

Comment: @Ypmits I am using unityengine.uielements....only UI gives an error

Comment: @RandRandom yes its declared in the same class and its public too

Answer (score 0):

Button actually is GameObject include Component Button. And you should init size for Array you want to create before using it. I had edited code for example:

```cs
 //Your array
 public GameObject[] levelButtons; 

 //Object to attach Button
 public GameObject   panelShow;
 //Size for Array
 public int          sizeArrayButton = 5;

 void Awake()
 {
        //Init size for Array
        levelButtons = new GameObject[sizeArrayButton];
        for (int i = 0; i < levelButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            //Create new Object and random for position of Gameobject
            GameObject button = new GameObject();
            button.transform.parent = panelShow.transform;
            button.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
            button.AddComponent<Button>();
            button.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(100, 50), Random.Range(100, 26), Random.Range(-25, 26));
            button.AddComponent<Image>();
            button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Debug.Log($"Button: +{i}+ was clicked"});
            levelButtons[i] = button;
        }
        
 }
```

And in Unity, you also make it by using List and Prefabs.

Comment: apparently UnityEngine.UI gives an Error so i used .UIElements

Comment: Did you include it on `using` ?

Comment: Hey...so the issue is fixed now....im really sorry i couldnt reply to you....but thank u very much for your time....check above for the solve....again thanks

Answer (score 0):

so the issue is solved...so basically what i did was just update my unity version and then it allowed me to use UnityEngine.UI and the issue is now fixed...

Thank you everyone for your time...much apppreciated